# jquery live hover

Tags: jquery, live, jquery-1.4

I'm using the following jquery code to show a contextual delete button only for table rows we are hovering with our mouse. This works but not for rows that have been added with js/ajax on the fly...

Is there a way to make this work with live events?

```
$("table tr").hover(
  function () {},
  function () {}
);
```

Answer (score 245, accepted):

jQuery 1.4.1 now supports "hover" for live() events, but only with one event handler function:

```
$("table tr").live("hover",

function () {

});
```

Alternatively, you can provide two functions, one for mouseenter and one for mouseleave:

```
$("table tr").live({
    mouseenter: function () {

    },
    mouseleave: function () {

    }
});
```

Comment: It still does not work for me though. I tried doing this: Where am i going wrong? > $('table tr').live('hover', function() {
  $(this).find('.deletebutton').toggle();
 });

Comment: this is incorrect and does not work. see the "Multiple Events" header under the documentation for `live`: http://api.jquery.com/live/

Comment: As of jQuery 1.4.2, .live("hover") is equivalent to .live("mouseover mouseout"), NOT .live("mouseenter mouseleave") - see http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/6077 So, do .live("mouseenter mouseleave", function() {...}), or .live("mouseenter", function() {...}).live("mouseleave", function() {...})

Comment: thank you @aem, this worked for me: $("table tr").live("mouseenter", function() {...}).live("mouseleave", function() {...});

Comment: thats brilliant, aside of mouseenter and mouseleave I assume you can use different actions (like onclick and such) here too?

Comment: As per the [JQuery `.live` documentation page](http://api.jquery.com/live/) it says to use `.on` instead. "As of jQuery 1.7, the .live() method is deprecated. Use .on() to attach event handlers."

Comment: Since `.live` is deprecated and `.on` doesn't work in some situations for elements added after the dom is loaded, see the last answer in [this SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9827095/is-it-possible-to-use-jquery-on-and-hover).

Answer (score 110):

```
$('.hoverme').live('mouseover mouseout', function(event) {
  if (event.type == 'mouseover') {
    // do something on mouseover
  } else {
    // do something on mouseout
  }
});
```

http://api.jquery.com/live/

Comment: Worked for me as well.  +1  Tried doing Philippe's version, both with mouseover and mouseenter - neither worked.  But this one did.  Thanks!

Comment: `.live` is deprecated now, see Andre's answer for replacement method now.

Comment: Using `mouseover` and `mouseout` events here will cause the code to continually fire as the user moves the mouse around inside the element. I think `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` are more appropriate since it'll only fire once upon entry.

Answer (score 61):

`.live()` has been deprecated as of jQuery 1.7

Use `.on()` instead and specify a descendant selector

http://api.jquery.com/on/

```
$("table").on({
  mouseenter: function(){
    $(this).addClass("inside");
  },
  mouseleave: function(){
    $(this).removeClass("inside");
  }
}, "tr");  // descendant selector
```

Comment: this works flawlessly as of jquery 1.9.  

all live and delegate solutions are DEPRECATED!

it would be awesome if someone could unaccept the accepted answer and accept this one instead.

Answer (score 5):

As of jQuery 1.4.1, the hover event works with `live()`. It basically just binds to the mouseenter and mouseleave events, which you can do with versions prior to 1.4.1 just as well:

```
$("table tr")
    .mouseenter(function() {
        // Hover starts
    })
    .mouseleave(function() {
        // Hover ends
    });
```

This requires two binds but works just as well.

Answer (score 5):

This code works:

```
    $(".ui-button-text").live(
        'hover',
        function (ev) {
            if (ev.type == 'mouseover') {
                $(this).addClass("ui-state-hover");
            }

            if (ev.type == 'mouseout') {
                $(this).removeClass("ui-state-hover");
            }
        });
```

Comment: What is "ui-state-hover"?  How does that apply to the user's original question?

Answer (score 2):

WARNING: There is a significant performance penalty with the live version of hover. It's especially noticeable in a large page on IE8.

I am working on a project where we load multi-level menus with AJAX (we have our reasons :). Anyway, I used the live method for the hover which worked great on Chrome (IE9 did OK, but not great). However, in IE8 It not only slowed down the menus (you had to hover for a couple seconds before it would drop), but everything on the page was painfully slow, including scrolling and even checking simple checkboxes.

Binding the events directly after they loaded resulted in adequate performance.

Comment: useful, but more a comment than an answer.

Answer (score 0):

You should use $(document). İf you dont use this, the new added table rows not works properly.

$(document).on("mouseover","table tr",function(event){

//show buttons

});

$(document).on("mouseout","table tr",function(event){

//hide buttons

});