# Jquery wont work on plugin generated html tags

Tags: jquery, dom, rss

I am developing a simple RSS aggregator site that basically parses a bunch of RSS feeds and displays them in a series of boxes. I am using the RSS plugin, [ZRSSFEED](http://www.zazar.net/developers/zrssfeed/).

You can see a live version of the site here: http://vitaminjdesign.com/adrian

The problem I am having is using jquery to select the DOM objects generated by the plugin. TO be more specific, I am trying to display social icons next to the anchor link when you hover over any link on the page using the following jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

        $('a').hover(function(){
            $('<a href="#"><img src="images/facebook.gif" class="facebook" alt="facebook"></a>').appendTo(this).fadeIn(500);
            $('<a href="#"><img src="images/twitter.gif" class="twitter" alt="twitter"></a>').appendTo(this).fadeIn(500);

        }, function(){
            $('a').find('.facebook,.twitter').stop().fadeOut(500);
        });
    });
```

For some reason, this jquery will not work with the anchors on the page. The plugin generates the a tags using a jquery script that is placed above this script in my HTML document. I cant seem to figure out why this isnt working!!! I have tried various jquery snippets that work on other elements of the page, but the plugin generated content doesn't seem to be affected by any jquery. HELP!

Comment: you can see it working if you hover over the logo link, but not the rest of the links

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This doesn't work because the DOM has changed since the page was first rendered, so you'll need to use the `live()` method. It allows for generated elements to still be targeted by  already-existing JQuery functions. http://api.jquery.com/live/

Comment: live is the way to do this, hoever, when you are working with a hover event, use the following code:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2262480/jquery-live-hover

Answer (score 0):

You should use the [live()](http://api.jquery.com/live/) or [delegate()](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) methods to bind events to elements that get added to the DOM after the initial render.

Answer (score 0):

If you only require the links of the feed to have the events attached, you can also use the callback function of zRSSFeed to apply them after the feed has loaded.

For example:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#test').rssfeed('http://feeds.bbc.co.uk/iplayer/highlights/tv/list',{}, function(e) {

        $(e).find('div.rssBody a').hover(function() {
            $('<a href="#"><img src="images/facebook.gif" class="facebook" alt="facebook"></a>').appendTo(this).fadeIn(500);
            $('<a href="#"><img src="images/twitter.gif" class="twitter" alt="twitter"></a>').appendTo(this).fadeIn(500);

        }, function(){
            $('a').find('.facebook,.twitter').stop().fadeOut(500);
        });

    });
});
```