# Attach an event immediately after setting up the HTML content

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

This is an example of my jQuery code that I use in a function to do pagination:

```
// new_content is a variable that holds the html I want to add to a div
$('div#my_div').html(new_content);
$("div#my_div a.details").hover(function(){         
    $(this).fadeIn(); //code to execute when the mouse get in
}, function(){
    $(this).fadeOut(); //code to execute when the mouse get out
});
```

BUT the `hover` event does not work at all, and I believe that this is caused because the DOM is not ready yet!

To get around this I used set up a timer like this:

```
$('div#my_div').html(new_content);

window.setTimeout(
  $("div#my_div a.details").hover(function(){           
    $(this).fadeIn(); //code to execute when the mouse get in
  }, function(){
    $(this).fadeOut(); //code to execute when the mouse get out
  });
,100);
```

I asked this question because I'm sure that this is not the right way to attach an event immediately after the html method (maybe it didn't it's work!).

si I hope someone show me the right way to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is better to use a delegate rather than live, as live is essentially a delegate on the document.body causing it to have to bubble much longer.

Here is an example using a delegate: http://jsfiddle.net/Akkuma/wLDpT/

Comment: first Thank you, i just tried your example it's good i will look in the documentation for details.

Comment: your code executes only the instructions in the else block, so i changed mouseenter by mouseover, & now it work perfectly.

Answer (score 2):

You would want to use the live `mouseover` `mouseleave` events

```
$("div#my_div").live({
       mouseenter: function()
       {

       },
       mouseleave: function()
       {

       }
    }
);
```

Alternately you could do:

```
$('div#my_div').live('mouseover mouseout', function(event) {
    if (event.type == 'mouseover') {
        // do something on mouseover
    } else {
        // do something on mouseout
    }
});
```

**UPDATE**

In newer versions of jQuery you can do it like this

```
$('body').on('mouseover','#my_div', function(){});
$('body').on('mouseout', '#my_div', function(){});
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you need to use the `live()` method. As you can read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2262480/jquery-live-hover), it seems that you will need to separate the two events:

```
.live("mouseenter", function() {...})
.live("mouseleave", function() {...});
```

**UPDATE:** Someone voted me up, so if someone gets here, I recommend to read the `on()` documentation ([here](http://api.jquery.com/on/)) as `live` was deprecated long ago. Also, it may be interesting to see `mouseenter()`([link](http://api.jquery.com/mouseenter/)) and `mouseleave()` ([link](https://api.jquery.com/mouseleave/)). The idea is the same as with `live`.

Answer (score 0):

you can check out .live function of jquery. Here is the link
http://api.jquery.com/live/