# jQuery :: live hover problem

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

An example jsfiddle is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/PXExS/2/). Try to hover the red square and then hover the blue one. Why is it flickering? How can I prevent the blue square to disappear?

(This is actually a tab and it's ex icon, that appear only when hovered)

JavaScript:

```
$("#foo").live("mouseover mouseout", function(e) {
    if (e.type == "mouseover") {
       $("#foo").append("<div id='bar'>");
    } else {
        $("#bar").remove();
    }
});
```

CSS:

```
#foo {
 width: 100px;
 height: 50px;
 background: red;   
}

#bar {
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
    background: blue;
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not sure what you intent todo, but is it  what you're looking for: http://jsfiddle.net/PXExS/4/

```
$("#foo").live("mouseenter mouseleave", function(e) {
    if (e.type == "mouseenter") {
       $("#foo").append("<div id='bar'>");
    } else {
        $("#bar").remove();
    }
});
```

Comment: Almost exactly the same as [my own conclusion](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/PXExS/6/), +1!

Comment: woh. thanks. I followed comment from [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2262480/jquery-live-hover): "As of jQuery 1.4.2, .live("hover") is equivalent to .live("mouseover mouseout"), NOT .live("mouseenter mouseleave") - see bugs.jquery.com/ticket/6077 So, do .live("mouseenter mouseleave", function() {...}), or .live("mouseenter", function() {...}).live("mouseleave", function() {...})". =/

Answer (score 4):

You can achieve the same thing by doing

```
$("#foo").live("hover", function(e) {
    $("#bar").toggle();
});
```

**Check working example at http://jsfiddle.net/PXExS/9/**