# Attaching jQuery/AJAX scripts to elements added using window.setInterval(, 1000*60) method

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, css

I have a problem with auto updating a div. I have a script as shown below which refreshes the page content (like facebook) every 1 minute. The problem is that this div is newly added to the page and that it contains some ajax/jQuery elements to add effects.

```
function loadNewPosts(){
        var id = $(".altbgcolor:first").attr("id");

        $.get('/update.php', { updateid: id ,catid:'technology'  }, function(data){
                                $(".newslist").prepend(data);
                            }, 'html');
     }

     window.setInterval(loadNewPosts, 1000*60)
```

Below is an example of div its supposed to populate if found via update.php

```
 <li class="altbgcolor" id=755>
                    <div>   <a href=http://mashup2.sunnydsouza.com/technology/755/ target="_blank" rel="nofollow">
                        <div class="newsthumb" center center no-repeat;"><img src="http://mashup2.sunnydsouza.com/timthumb.php?src=/images/tech/thumb-755.jpg&h=100&w=100&zc=1&a=t"  /></div>
                        </a>


                        <div class="newstext" style="margin:0px;">

                        <a href=http://mashup2.sunnydsouza.com/technology/755/full/ target=_blank style="text-decoration:none; "><h1 style="color:#081C28;"><img width="11" height="9" src="/content/icon_topic_newest.gif"> Top 5 Android Apps for Travel &nbsp;</h1></a>
                        <!--<i><font color=red size=1.2>Technology</font></i><br>-->

                    <div style="font-size: 0.4em; color:#666666;">  
                        <!-- AddThis Button BEGIN -->
                        <!--<span class="st_email" st_url="http://mashup2.sunnydsouza.com/technology/755/" st_title="Top 5 Android Apps for Travel" ></span>
                        <span class="st_facebook" st_url="http://mashup2.sunnydsouza.com/technology/755/" st_title="Top 5 Android Apps for Travel" ></span>
                        <span class="st_twitter" st_url="http://mashup2.sunnydsouza.com/technology/755/" st_title="Top 5 Android Apps for Travel" ></span>
                        <script type="text/javascript">var addthis_config = {"data_track_clickback":true};</script>
                        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://s7.addthis.com/js/250/addthis_widget.js#username=sunnydsouza"></script>-->
                        <!-- AddThis Button END -->



                        <span style="text-decoration:none; color:none; "><i> via <a href="#" style="text-decoration: none;color:#105289 ;" onmouseover="this.style.textDecoration = 'underline'" onmouseout="this.style.textDecoration = 'none'">demo1</a></i></span>                           

                        <span style="text-decoration:none; color:none; ">
                        <a class="example7" href="comments_3.php?id=755" style="text-decoration:none; color:#666666; "><img src="content/comment/comments.png" width=18 height=18><i>No comments</i></a></span>

                        <span style="text-decoration:none; color:none; margin:5px;"><img src="content/voting/eye.png" >  17</span>                          
                        <!-- Vote Buttons #vote-->  


                        <span class="vote"  id="755" name="up" style="text-decoration:none; color:none; margin:5px; ">
                        <img src="/content/voting/yes-enb.png" width=12 height=12 alt=""> 
                        <span style="text-decoration:none; color:none">1 </span></span>

                        &nbsp;



                        <!-- Vote Buttons ENDS #vote--> 
                        <br>
                        <i><font color=red size=1.2>Technology</font></i>

                        </div>

                        <!--<h1><a href=http://mashup2.sunnydsouza.com/technology/755/full/ class="more" target="_blank" rel="nofollow">read...</a></h1>-->


                        </div><div class="clear"></div>
                     </div>

                     <div class="sharedp">
                        <span class="st_email" st_url="http://mashup2.sunnydsouza.com/technology/755/" st_title="Top 5 Android Apps for Travel" ></span>
                        <span class="st_facebook" st_url="http://mashup2.sunnydsouza.com/technology/755/" st_title="Top 5 Android Apps for Travel" ></span>
                        <span class="st_twitter" st_url="http://mashup2.sunnydsouza.com/technology/755/" st_title="Top 5 Android Apps for Travel" ></span>
                     </div>
                     </li>
```

Though the above code calls the update.php every 1 minute and adds elements to the current page. The current div is devoid on the javascript element

This is the javascript on the main page which attaches itself to every div on every element initially to the span class="vote" 
            // thumbs up / thumbs down code

```
$(function() {
            $(".vote").click(function()
            {
            var id = $(this).attr("id");
            var name = $(this).attr("name");
            var dataString = 'id='+ id ;
            var parent = $(this);

            if (name=='up')
            {
            //$(this).fadeIn(200).html('<img src="/content/voting/yes-enb.JPG" />');
            $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "up_vote.php",
            data: dataString,
            cache: false,

            success: function(html)
            {
            parent.find('span').html(html);
            }
            });
            }

 return false;
 });
 });
```

However for the new elements added during the auto update, when clicking on the vote button..nothing happens.

Why is this happening. Why is the jQuery mentioned in the page at start not working for the auto newly added divs?

Please help

**EDIT::** I have 2 more javascript elements. How do i convert them to .live ?

```
     $(document).ready(function(){


   $(".altbgcolor").hover(function() {
            $(this)
                .addClass('altbgcolor-active')
                .find(".sharedp")
                .slideDown('slow');
        },function () {
            $(this)
                .removeClass('altbgcolor-active')
                .find(".sharedp")
                .slideUp('slow');
        });
 $(".example7").colorbox({
            onOpen:function(){ alert('onOpen: colorbox is about to open'); },
            onLoad:function(){ alert('onLoad: colorbox has started to load the targeted content'); },
            onComplete:function(){ alert('onComplete: colorbox has displayed the loaded content'); },
            onCleanup:function(){ alert('onCleanup: colorbox has begun the close process'); },
            onClosed:function(){ alert('onClosed: colorbox has completely closed'); }
 )};

 });
```

**EDIT2:** This is what I am trying, Please validate if its correct...

```
$(".altbgcolor").live('hover',function() {
            $(this)
                .addClass('altbgcolor-active')
                .find(".sharedp")
                .slideDown('slow');
        },function () {
            $(this)
                .removeClass('altbgcolor-active')
                .find(".sharedp")
                .slideUp('slow');
        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(function() {
       $(".vote").live('click', function () {
            var id = $(this).attr("id");
            var name = $(this).attr("name");
            var dataString = 'id='+ id ;
            var parent = $(this);
            if (name=='up')
            {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "up_vote.php",
                    data: dataString,
                    cache: false,
                    success: function (html) {
                        parent.find('span').html(html);
                    }
                });
            }
            return false;
      });
 });
```

Comment: Thanks veidelis, it worked properly. I have 2 more jQuery elemts i would like to convert o live(). I have edited my main question. Please could you help me achieve the same. I tried editing myself but it gives funny results :( maybe because its enclosed within document ready function

Comment: Those events should work properly regardless of being wrapped in $.ready() or not. $.live() is not always the best option though. You should be looking to use [$.delegate()](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/)

Comment: Please check the code I edited in my question above.(edit2). tried using the live, but i have 2 functions for hover... please correct if am wrong. seems on the mouseenter event is handled. Also how can i use the colorbox plugin using the live or delegate function?

Comment: Please, see this question: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2262480/jquery-live-hover](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2262480/jquery-live-hover)

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered jQuery's [`live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) for this? It will attach the eventhandler to **all current and future elements**.

Comment: How do i convert the above and map it as .live() ? Could you please help a little. Thanks for the prompt response