# jQuery hover() not firing

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm ajaxing some search results onto a page, and trying to do stuff when the user hovers over results. Here's what I've got:

```
$(".preview").live("hover", function(){ console.log('hovered');} )
```

Each of the results has the class "preview". Why isn't anything happening?

Edit: Here's where the HTML is coming from:

```
var preview="<img class='previews' src='http://i.ytimg.com/vi/"+vid+"/default.jpg' />  ";
```

Comment: Check if this can help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2262480/jquery-live-hover

Comment: If you are using jQuery 1.4.1 or higher (which allows you to use `hover` with the `.live()` function, then I see nothing wrong with this jQuery code.  The issue would likely be with your HTML which you haven't shared.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your selector is for the class "preview", and your actual html is with the class "previews": Your selector will never match the element ;)

Comment: @aloishis Well, sometimes it's nice for the problem to be that simple. You should be glad you didn't have to do anything complicated.