# change bg color on hover, jquery

Tags: php, jquery, hover

I have this piece of code that works great, but as soon as I refresh a div on my page, the code breaks, and .item_control_box is no longer hidden, I'm thinking I have to rewrite this to work with .live, but I'm not sure how.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".item_control_box").hide();
    jQuery('.each_item_container').hover(function() {
        jQuery(this).find('.item_control_box').show()
    }, function() {
        jQuery(this).find('.item_control_box').hide();
    });
});
```

Thanks!

Comment: See this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2262480/jquery-live-hover

Comment: What does the HTML look like. Or at least post it on jsfiddle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you re-loading your div dynamically via AJAX? Just curious. Here's what I see:

You current js code will run when the document is rendered

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".item_control_box").hide();
```

^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

this will hide all CURRENT elements with class item_control_box that are already present

```
jQuery('.each_item_container').hover(function() {
    jQuery(this).find('.item_control_box').show()
}, function() {
    jQuery(this).find('.item_control_box').hide();
});
```

^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

Attach hover event handler to all CURRENT elements with class each_item_container and then find children of item_control_box on hover.

});

If you are loading new data into your div via AJAX or another means you need to ensure two things:

1) elements with item_control_box are not displayed at first. This you can accomplish with simple style="display:none;"

2) ensure that hover events are assigned to .each_item_container. This you need to do via live method jQuery('.each_item_container').live('hover', function()...  described by @PeterStuart

Last but not least, not sure what version jquery you are using but in 1.7+ live() method is deprecated. use on() method instead. Here's the link for reference: http://api.jquery.com/live/

Answer (score 1):

You would change:

```
jQuery('.each_item_container').hover(function() {
```

to

```
jQuery('.each_item_container').live('hover', function() {
```

To answer on your comment above your HTML should just be fine, as long if you have a div class called "each_item_container". When you hover over it is should now change your backreound color:)

Let me know if it doesn't work:)

Comment: Didn't work.  I think the problem is with $(".item_control_box").hide(); Is there a way to add .live to this?

Comment: Try changeing $(".item_control_box").hide(); to 
$(".item_control_box").live('hide');

Comment: Hmm.. sorry I'm out :/ I'm sure someone else will post, hope you get it :)