# jQuery : issue with .live()

Tags: jquery

This works ( `.hover` ):

```
$('a.directory:not(.trashContent), a.file:not(.trashContent)').hover(function() {
    if (!dragged) $(this).find('a.suppr:first').show();
}, function() {
    $(this).find('a.suppr:first').hide();
});
```

And this does not work ( `.live('hover')` ):

```
$('a.directory:not(.trashContent), a.file:not(.trashContent)').live('hover', function() {
    if (!dragged) $(this).find('a.suppr:first').show();
}, function() {
    $(this).find('a.suppr:first').hide();
});
```

Any idea why?

Comment: `'hover'` is not an event type. `hover()` is a custom shorthand method defined by jQuery.

Comment: fyi, `live` is considered to be deprecated in newer versions of jquery.

Comment: Have you tried mouseout and mouseover events instead?

Comment: @Šime Vidas: That's an answer!

Comment: Your answer is here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2262480/jquery-live-hover

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason why it doesn't work is, that hover is not really a single event. It binds together the event handlers for mouseenter and mouseleave.
Means hover itself is not really an own event handler. To make it work with live (**better use .on()** ) you must use the event handlers seperated.

```
$("#Element").live({
  mouseenter:function(){
    //do something
  },
  mouseleave:function(){
    //do something
  }
});
```

Comment: the `live` method is deprecated, if using jquery version 1.7+ use `on` or else use `delegate`

Answer (score -2):

.live is old. Since jQuery 1.7 there is a total new Event API in jQuery and you should use [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on) for all events.

An example:

```
$('a.directory:not(.trashContent), a.file:not(.trashContent)').on('mouseenter', function() {
  console.log('You have hovered on ' + $(this));
});
```

---

And you can better select elements combinated with [`.is()`](http://api.jquery.com/is):

```
$('a.directory, a.file').is(':not(.trashContent)', function() {
  var $elem = jQuery(this);
  $elem.on('mouseenter', function() {
     console.log('You have hovered on ' + $elem);
  });
});
```

Comment: Did you notice you are doing `.is` wrong, which is kind of ironic since the documentation link is just above it.

Comment: Your answer doesn't answer the question at all.

Comment: @Esailija, ah yes. I notice, I will remove it.  I always write the doc link without go to the doc page...