# Dynamic content mouse over and out

Tags: jquery

I have some divs that are created with data from a json string. Most of them are images. Over those dynamic loaded images and want to show a div when mouse over it and hide when you mouse out. Therefore I used the live function, found it here on the forum. 
The mouse over function works but it won't mouse out. So when I hover one image the div shows up but when I mouse out the div is still visible. Any suggestions on this?

My code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('.product').live("hover", function() {
        $(this).find('.product').stop(false,true); // get the image where hovering
        $(this).find('div.caption').stop(false,true).fadeIn(100); // and fade in
    },
     function() {
        $(this).find('.product').stop(false,true); // on mouse leave hide it  
        $(this).find('div.caption').stop(false,true).fadeOut(100); // fade out
     });
</script>
```

**UPDATED ANSWER**
Thanks to the help below I found the solution.

```
$(".productsGrid .product").live("mouseenter", function() {$(this).find('.product').stop(false,true);
$(this).find('div.caption').stop(false,true).fadeIn(100);})
$(".productsGrid .product").live("mouseleave", function() { $(this).find('.product').stop(false,true);   
$(this).find('div.caption').stop(false,true).fadeOut(100);});
```

Comment: Try using mouseenter instead of hover

Comment: @KaiQing - .hover() binds handlers for both mouseenter and mouseleave events.

Comment: if you are using jquery 1.7.2 or up you should switch to on() I have had issues where live is buggy when using 1.7.2 since it is deprecated.

Comment: also are you sure $('.product') will also find another $('.product') inside ($(this).find('.product'))?

Comment: is this code in document.ready?

Comment: @Huangism: No I'm not sure... I'm pretty new to jquery so can you provide an example?

Comment: @Huangism: no it's not document is ready FYI

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that `live` only takes one function parameter, not 2 in the way that the `hover` function does.  Using `hover` with `live` basically just binds the one function to both `mouseenter` and `mouseleave`.

You can see an explanation and solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2262480/jquery-live-hover).

However, unless you are using a version of jquery prior to 1.7, you should not be using `live` as it is deprecated.  You should instead use `on`.

Your code would look something like this:

```
$(STATIC ANCESTOR).on({ 
        mouseenter: 
           function() 
           { 

           }, 
        mouseleave: 
           function() 
           { 

           } 
       }, ".product"
    );
```

Where `STATIC ANCESTOR` is replaced with an ancestor element of your `.product` elements which is not dynamically loaded.  If needed `document` can be used but should only be used as a last resort.

Comment: Ok thx... this works for me!! I updated my question with the right answer, 
    '